# Group by column values with spaces Using linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have got this situation with a *datatable* like this

**`C1 C2 C3 
 A  AA 4 
    BB 6
 B  CC 3
    DD 3
    EE 4
 C  FF 5
    GG 5`**

and my output should be like this

**`C1 C2       C3 
 A  AA,BB    10 
 B  CC,DD,EE 10
 C  FF,GG    10`**

How can i group by the column with the space till the next value comes up

What i did was i took all the **row itemarray** and then using some string manipulation and regex got the row value as for the first two values like this and assigned to a variable in a query using **Let**
**A,AA,BB,10|B,CC,DD,EE,10** but then i cannot add it using the 
**DT.clone.rows.Add(x.split("|"c))* method as there its not incrementing and adding the whole joined string

Any other input where i can manipulate and add it (P.S i know linq is querying language)

Thank you for your time

Comment: as the order is not guaranteed you can not use groupby, but only takewhile

Comment: I would like to see the select command that created that DataTable.

Comment: hello @AshkanMobayenKhiabani yes the order is not guaranteed but the order would be same to get the rows values till the next values appears hence takewhile would be the best bet......Can you provide an example related to this scenario i have never used **take while** thank you for your time

Comment: Hello @Mary this data is auto generated

Comment: What does "auto generated" mean? It came from somewhere.

Comment: is the data from something like Excel Pivot Table? Seems much harder to achieve with LINQ than with for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello All first of all Thank you for your time and effort i Did this use case using this code
This gave me all row item array in string and than in the end with a little **Split** method i was able to add it to my datatable

````
String.Join("|",(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String.Join("|",(From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Select String.Join(",",roww.ItemArray) ).ToList),"\|,",",")).Split("|"c).
Select(Function(q)CStr(q)+","+CStr(String.join("|",System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(CStr(q),"\d+").Cast(Of match)).Split("|"c).Sum(Function(r) CInt(r) ))).tolist),",\d+,",",")```
````

Comment: Recheck what end query is getting generated at db. It would not be optimal to use `AsEnumerable()` if data grows gradually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.GroupBy` to get result needed

Here is your class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string C1 { get; set; }
    public string C2 { get; set; }
    public int C3 { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine that you have list of `Data` objects, so your `GroupBy` expression will be following:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(g => g.C1, (a, b) => new {C1 = a, C2 = b.ToList()})
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.C1,
        C2 = string.Join(",", g.C2.Select(m => m.C2)),
        C3 = g.C2.Sum(m => m.C3)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: hello @Roman.Pavelko thank you for your time this would but i cannot create a class as i have to implement it in tool and hence in that tools its not possible to create a class.......is there a way to do this using linq query........Another thing did you notice the space in the datatable if i group by using the column 1 it'll create a group for spaces as well so there would be another row of values containing the space values

Comment: I am sorry, @Vickydas, I haven't noticed empty values and how they should be grouped. I tend to think that there is no easy way to do that using simple linq query. In order to complete this task, I would split it into 2 steps: 1. get all items from DB and apply initial grouping using simple "for" loop (merge all child items that have empty C1 column into their parent); 2. apply normal grouping using linq on this result like I shown in the answer.

Comment: Hello @Roman.Pavelko yes but is there a way where i can do both the steps using linq thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

A simple `.GroupBy` can give you expected result, Edited to handle `Null` or `WhiteSpace` Columns

```
var res = ListModel.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.C1)
                  && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.C2))
        .GroupBy(e => e.C1).Select(e => new
        {
         e.Key,
         c2 = string.Join(",", e.Select(x => x.C2).ToList()),
         c3 = e.Sum(x => x.C3)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello @Sushant Yelpale thank you for your time.....If i use this code it'll group by the column1 but as you can see there are spaces or null values in my datatable it'll create a group of null values with its corresponding row values

Comment: Hello @SushantYelpale your code will ignore the blank values but i also want the blank values with the previous data did you see the input and output properly? please check it once.........i need the blank values with the previous not null value grouped together check it once

Answer (score 0):

Try following code which is tested

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("C3", typeof(int));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", "AA", 4});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "BB", 6});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", "CC", 3});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "DD", 3});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "EE", 4});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", "FF", 5});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "GG", 5});

            //replace nulls in column 1 with actual values
            string previous = "";
            foreach(DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                if (row.Field<string>("C1") == null)
                {
                    row["C1"] = previous;
                }
                else
                {
                    previous = row.Field<string>("C1");
                }
            }

            DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

            var groups = dt1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("C1")).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    group.Key,
                    string.Join(",", group.Select(x => x.Field<string>("C2"))),
                    group.Select(x => x.Field<int>("C3")).Sum()
                });
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your teachers would also take points for many reasons in this code:

Comment: 1) Calling `AsEnumerable()` multiple times in the same scope instead of using variables `(dt1.AsEnumerable())`.

Comment: 2) Doing unnecessary `ToList()` for the `groups` variable.

Comment: 3) Using two extension methods in `group.Select(x => x.Field<int>("C3")).Sum()` while you can use just one like `group.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("C3"))`.

Comment: I use ToList() so the OP can actually see the results.  If you don't use ToList() than you can't hover over the variables and see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way using `Skip`, `TakeWhile`, and `GroupBy` extensions:

```cs
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("C3", typeof(int));

//The output table.
DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", "AA", 3 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "BB", 6 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", "CC", 3 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "DD", 3 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "EE", 4 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", "FF", 5 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "GG", 6 });

var rows = dt1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().AsEnumerable();

foreach (var row in rows.Where(r => r.Field<string>("C1") != null))
{
    var indx = dt1.Rows.IndexOf(row) + 1;

    var q = rows
        .Skip(indx) 
        .TakeWhile(t => t.Field<string>("C1") == null)
        .GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("C1"))
        .Select(g => new
        {
            C1 = row.Field<string>("C1"),
            C2 = $"{row.Field<string>("C2")}, {string.Join(", ", g.Select(s => s.Field<string>("C2")))}",
            C3 = row.Field<int>("C3") + g.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("C3")),
        }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (q != null)
        dt2.Rows.Add(q.C1, q.C2, q.C3);                
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;
```

The idea behind this snippet is to:

- Get the complete rows and iterate through them.
- For each complete row, we get it's index from the original `DataTable` and add 1 to make a starting search point for the incomplete rows. The `Skip` extension  is the method to achieve that.
- The `TakeWhile` extension function gets the incomplete rows and stops at the next complete row.
- The `GroupBy` extension function groups the incomplete rows to concatenate their `C2` values and sum their `C3` values, add the results to the values of the complete row and create a temporary anonymous object to hold these values.
- Extract the anonymous object and add a new `DataRow` to the output DataTable.
- And finally, bind the output DataTable to a DGV.

[image: Q59513482]

Happy 2020 for all.

Comment: Why is your code better than mine?  My teachers in college took away points for code that was not understandable.  It is important that others can easily understand the code and maintain.

Comment: It is not a great idea to enumerate rows inside a enumeration of rows.  Your loop is in the order of N*N + N [due to var indx = dt1.Rows.IndexOf(row) + 1;]  If I wrote the code I would use two for loops with i and j index like a sort.